# How to Enable default security groups

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Recently, we found the features

- when we created the account via API, there is no default Security Groups.
- Once we accessed to security groups menu(Security >> Network Security >> Security Groups) on softalyer portal(control.sortlayer.com), default security groups are created.

> Default security groups is allow_all, allow_http, allow_https,
>   allow_outbound, allow_ssh

When creating a account via api, how to enable default security groups ?

additionally, we tried the bellow job

- when we created a account, create the same default groups

as a result, there are two same security group about each security groups.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the default Security Groups the same that the control portal you have to use the following service and method after the account has been created.

[SoftLayer_Network_SecurityGroup::getAllObjects](https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_SecurityGroup/getAllObjects/)

It seems that you can create any security group, it does not matter if it is one that already exists.